# Jquery object converted to normal variable after minifying with RequireJS optimizer r.js

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, requirejs-optimizer

I have this function in CoffeeScript

```
render: -> 
_.each @$elements, ($el) =>
  if $el[0].id is 'tabs-div'
    emptySlate = "<div class='js-empty-slate' style='padding:40px;'><h3>no data available</h3><div>"
    @setEmptyPlacholde($el, emptySlate)
    return 

  @setEmptyPlacholde($el)


setEmptyPlacholde: ($el, emptySlate)->
emptySlateHTML = emptySlate or "<h3 class='js-empty-slate'>no data available</h3>"
if $el.hasClass('mobile-os-con') or 
   $el.hasClass('time-of-visit-con') or 
   $el.hasClass('gender-visit-con') or 
   $el.hasClass('time-redemption-sales-con') or 
   $el.hasClass('gender-redemption-con')

  $el.children().hide()
else
  $el.empty()
$el.append emptySlateHTML
```

$elements is a jQuery variable which uses array like this:

```
$elements: [
$("#tabs-div")
$("#visits-male")
$("#visits-female")
$("#days-of-visits")
$(".time-of-visit-con")
]
```

When I used RequireJS optimizer `r.js` which uses `Uglify` the generated minified code .. looks like this:

```
render:function(){var e=this;return _.each(this.$elements,function(t){var n;if(t[0].id==="tabs-div"){n="<div class='js-empty-slate' style='padding:40px;'><h3>no data available</h3><div>",e.setEmptyPlacholde(t,n);return}return e.setEmptyPlacholde(t)})}
```

In the previous minified code, the `$el` became `t` .. So this refused to execute the `$el` as jQuery element in the production.

This is the problem but I don't know why this occurs. Can anyone explain why this happens for me, thanks.

**Update:** The minified code was not the problem but the script executed before the nodes in the array load properly ,however I am invoking the function after document be **ready** which means the DOM must be fully loaded.

**Hint:** I am putting the script tag in the  ,and this works properly when the code is not minified.

Comment: This is not the same code.  Your minified code references a `selector` property whereas the unminified code references `id`.  In addition, the unminified code indexes into the element; the minified code does not.  Are you sure you posted the correct example?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was sharing another minified code that I was just playing with. Now, I have updated it with the right minified code. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: The minified code looks good to me, it's the exact same thing as the coffeescript code. It doesn't matter that `$el` is now `t` it's just a local name for a variable that is only in scope for the `_.each` function invocation

Comment: Yes, this was not a problem of the minified code. But, the nodes in the array didn't load properly ,before the script being executed. so the `t` didn't work as intended as a jquery object which holds a node (this happens after minifying the code, however I am putting the script to be executed after document `ready` event)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `<div class='js-empty-slate' style='padding:40px;'><h3>no data available</h3><div>` <- doesn't appear to be closed properly.

As far as the variable..this appears to be default behavior for `UgliyJS`, it's simply shortening the variable name you provided as a part of optimization. It should not cause any issue...however if you want to prevent it, try adding `uglify: { no_mangle: true }` to `r.js` optimizer settings under options:

```
english: {
  ..your settings...
  options: {
   ...your other options...
    uglify: {
      no_mangle: true
    },
  }
}
```

For Uglify2, use this instead:

```
uglify2: {
  mangle: false
}
```

Comment: @nouran-mahmoud not sure if you down-voted or someone else...can you share your settings?

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer, but I believe that the point is not in not minifying the function or variable names. I want to know why it didn't work properly when it is minified ,however it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just on a purely technical note you can improve the code with things like -

```
$elements: $("#tabs-div,#visits-male,#visits-female,#days-of-visits,.time-of-visit-con")
```

and

```
$elements.filter("#tabs-div")
```

As for the variable renaming - variable names make absolutely no difference to anything except when it's for a public API - so a code minifier/uglifier will change the variable names to the shortest possible, in other words starting at a single character, and often in a random order (though some start at a,b,c etc). By default the uglifier will understand that `window` etc is global and not rename it.

Unless you're wrapping everything in a closure you should start with something like `$: window["jQuery"]` so your local var `$` will be correct when the variable renaming occurs and it will be pointing at the right thing.

If wrapping everything in a closure (wrap a function around everything can call it immediately) then you would pass jQuery as an argument - often you'd also pass longer named global vars that also get used like `window` and `document`.

Generally you include your script at the end of the HTML, or wrap it within a `$()` which is equivalent to the document.ready state.